# conditional formatting on contigious blank cells

Tags: excel

I am trying to create an attendance register where absence on continuous weeks (i.e. contigious blank cells) will gradually change colour.  Week one non attendance (green) week 2 (amber) week 3 (red) etc.  if an attendance then happens the next cell is populated with "y".  the colour scale should then stop.  if another blank cell (non attendance) occurs then i want the colour scale to begin again.  Each row is one person.  I know how to colour blank cells and count blank cells but wonder if this possible?

Comment: Sample data together with the expected results would have improved this question a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

See if the attached file helps ; I have used a helper row.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oelryafp6kffla3/Kate_Large_Book2.xlsx?dl=0

If you have a new person in every row , you can shift the helper row to start from the first unused column in the same row.